# RadGrid ItemCommand Doesn't Fire When Added In Code-Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am using a Telerik RadGrid in an ASP.NET website and I need to programmatically add an ItemCommand event handler from my page's PreRender event:

`MyGrid.ItemCommand += new GridCommandEventHandler(OnItemCommand);`

However, `OnItemCommand` is never called. If I put it in the .aspx file it works fine: `OnItemCommand="OnItemCommand"`, just not when I add it in C#.

What's going on here? TYIA.

Comment: Does it work when you subscribe to the event on PageLoad?

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you have not added this event in either in pageload or pageinit event.

Comment: It doesn't work there either

Comment: Have you tried adding the auto post back to true?

Comment: Where? The RadGrid doesn't seem to have that property.

Comment: One second let me get to my laptop and I'll figure it out for you. I'm on my phone right now. Until then in the markup, you should be able to make the postback to true or set it in the properties in the right hand pane

Comment: Ok, now that I am able to read the question properly...rdmptn is right its how I do it. I do it the markup and haven't come across your situation before...If I add it in the markup then it generates the method in the code behind and is accessed that way

Comment: It's working now; see my comment on rdmptn's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the handler when you create the grid (in Page_Load or Page_Init): http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-programmatic-creation.html. Or, simply in the markup. If you need it to fire only on a certain condition, you can add that condition inside the handler itself and exit it.

EDIT:
Try using the following code as base as it worked fine for me:

```
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
            <MasterTableView>
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

and server side:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1.ItemCommand += RadGrid1_ItemCommand;
}

protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}


protected DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description"));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ParameterName"));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ThirdColumn"));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FourthColumn"));
    tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { "firstRecord1", "firstRecord2", "firstRecord3", "firstRecord4" });
    tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { "secondRecord1", "secondRecord2", "secondRecord3", "secondRecord4" });
    tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { "thirdRecord1", "thirdRecord2", "thirdRecord3", "thirdRecord4" });
    tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { "fourthRecord1", "fourthRecord2", "fourthRecord3", "fourthRecord4" });
    return tbl;
}


protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1.DataSource=GetData();
}
```

Comment: I am creating the grid in the markup, but I need to add the handler in code, since I'm doing it in a Page subclass that several pages inherit from. But it doesn't work even if I do it in Page_Load or Page_Init.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a sample that works fine for me. Start from it and apply your setup to see what breaks the handler.

Comment: It works when I put it in Page_Load *and* I needed to call it even on postbacks. I was using `if (!Page.Postback)`